# How to initialize a node from the other scene in the instanced scene?

Tags: godot, gdscript

So, I have an instanced scene with kinematicBody2D Soldier. I previously wrote a script where it was getting the position of an "enemy" sprite and "drawing" a circle around it. If soldier enters this area, he rotates to the sprite and starts shooting.
Here is the old code:

```
#   Spotting an enemy and firing
    if (position.x - enemy_sprite.position.x) * (position.x - enemy_sprite.position.x) + (position.y - enemy_sprite.position.y) * (position.y - enemy_sprite.position.y) < detection_radius*detection_radius: #checking if a soldier is in detection radius of the enemy sprite
        var enemy = enemy_sprite.position - self.position 
        rotation = enemy.angle() + deg2rad(90)
        if (bullets > 0 && canFire):
            auto_fire()
    else:
        rotation = trans.angle() + deg2rad(90)#
```

Problem is, soldier is no longer a part of the main scene, he's instanced. 
How do I get the enemy sprite node into the instanced object script?

Comment: Hi there. Sorry, I don't have time at the moment to investigate/answer your question fully, but try having a look here, it might be what you're looking for. --https://godotengine.org/qa/15081/how-to-get-node-from-another-scene

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, I've just found a solution: if I use global variables, I can create a null node and init it later in the script of the main scene's script

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you could use an Area2D for your circle area. Area2D has an Signal to detect if a body entered it and gives you the body. There you can check if the body is an "Soldier" of yours and if so, set it to a variable in your enemy to work for it as long as it is in the area. Area2D has an signal for leaving the area also, so you can clear your target if the soldier leaves